# Blackberry 10 string constant file support

Tags: string, blackberry-10

I am looking for Blackberry 10 string constant definition file. Where I place application strings like in Android we have string.xml

Comment: is there any problem if you made your own file ? place it where ever you want what is the problem ?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi can u plz elaborate yout post so that I'll have some idea on it. I mean to say, where I place, how I read.

Comment: Sorry man i got a mistake, it seems that you are not developing and android application right ? it's a new OS called 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default file on BlackBerry 10 projects where you should put your string constants, I usually add a `common.hpp` header file with my string constants and access it anywhere by including the header file.

Example of common.hpp :
https://github.com/RodgerLeblanc/Extend/blob/master/ExtendService/src/common.hpp